# Make a list of hex characters from range

Tags: python, hex

I'm trying to write a list with hex characters that's for example 14 characters long starting with FFFFFFFFFFFFFF and ends at 2FFFFFFFFFFFFFF, I'm fairly new to computer language. I have some knowledge of python and other languages, I attempted to do a script with itertools and product but it wasn't the way I wanted to be . Any help?

Comment: Do you realize that list will have 1.44E17, ie 144 million billion, elements?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might harness `%X` format code for this task, consider following simple example: `list` from `0xA0` to `0xCF` (inclusive)

```
numbers = ["%X" % i for i in range(0xA0,0xCF+0x1)] # range is inclusive-exclusive, so we need 0x1
print(numbers)
```

output

```
['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7', 'A8', 'A9', 'AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'AE', 'AF', 'B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'B9', 'BA', 'BB', 'BC', 'BD', 'BE', 'BF', 'C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9', 'CA', 'CB', 'CC', 'CD', 'CE', 'CF']
```

Note there are two codes for hex-formatting `%X` use `0123456789ABCDEF` whilst `%x` use `0123456789abcdef`

Comment: thank you sooooo much!